# Interpolation of some Sobolev spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, sobolev-spaces, hilbert-spaces, interpolation-spaces

Let $X_0=L^2(0,1)$, $X_1=H^4(0,1)$, $X_2=H^4(0,1)\cap H^2_0(0,1)$. We know the interpolation space $$(X_0,X_1)_{1/2,2}=H^2(0,1).$$
I am wondering what is
$$(X_0,X_2)_{1/2,2}=?$$

Would it be $H^2_0(0,1)$?